2 gates and three guards
The Three Guards and the Two Gates
I created this riddle 25 years ago, who can solve this?
You find yourself standing in front of two gates—one leading to Heaven and the other to Hell. There are three guards standing nearby, each at one of the gates. Two of them always tell the truth, while one is a confuser, meaning this guard sometimes tells the truth and sometimes lies with the sole purpose of misleading you.
You are allowed to ask two yes/no questions in total. Each question can only be directed to one guard at a time. After asking your two questions, you must choose the gate that leads to Heaven.
How do you determine which gate leads to Heaven?

If the answer to a question is inconclusive (e. g. asking a question about the response the confuser would give), would a truth-teller answer "I don't know" or just pick at random?

By "sole purpose of misleading you", would I assume the confuser will always provide the answer that leads you to the most incorrect conclusion, i.e. if answering Q with A would allow you to correctly determine gate 1 is heaven, confuser would answer ~A?

@timuzhti Not OP, but I don't think that actually matters, because for a 100% accurate solution you need to assume the worst anyway.

@ilikecorgis I suppose it is true that for it to be usefully distinguished from, e.g., a guard that merely answers randomly, there would have to be a situation which Random is limited to specific answers that Confuser is not, and such a question is required (e.g., assuming "I don't know" is a possible answer, but Random only chooses between yes and no) and you're thus correct that it does not seem to be applicable here.

Welcome to PSE (Puzzling Stack Exchange)!  Cool puzzle!

Near duplicates. Same idea as those prior questions


 Ask Guard A: "Is Guard B the confuser"?


 There are 3 cases:


 Case 1: A is the confuser. The answer may be yes or no.


 Case 2: B is the confuser. The answer is yes.


 Case 3: C is the confuser. The answer is no.


 If the answer is yes, C is not the confuser. If the answer is no, B is not the confuser. So in 1 question, you can identify a person who is not the the confuser. Ask that person "Is the left door to Heaven?". Take the left door if you get a yes answer and the right door if you get a no answer.


Absolutely correct, no where on the internet yet, if appears in Quora or Reddit I was still me. Surprisingly almost no one I asked live got the answer within 10 min , how long did it take you?
